# how to match list of strings in a data frame and return the values in a new column by name of the list

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, stringr

```
library(stringr) 

cat.keys <- list(Internship='Intern', 
    Information.Technology=c('IT', 'Information Technology', 'Software', 'Developer'), 
    Healthcare=c('RN', 'LPN', 'Doctor', 'Nurse'), 
    Maintenance=c('Custodian', 'Janitor'))

jobs.df <- data.frame(Company=c('Big Brothers Big Sisters', 'Big Brothers Big Sisters', 
    'Big Brothers Big Sisters', 'American Red Cross', 'American Red Cross', 
    'American Red Cross', 'DeMolay International', 'Legal Aid Association', 
    'St.Mary’s Church'), 
    Job.Title = c('Intern', 'Marketing Intern', 'Special Events Internship Program', 
    'RN', 'Nurse', 'Registered Nurse', 'Director of IT - DeMolay International', 
    'SWITCHBOARD/INTAKE SPECIALIST', 'CHURCH CUSTODIAN - part-time'))
lapply(jobs.df$Job.Title, 
    function(x) sapply(cat.keys, function(y) str_detect(x, fixed(y))))
```

Comment: The question is not quite clear. It's valuable that you provided sample input code; sample output (at least for one input record) would be even better.

Comment: Here jobs.df is my data frame, cat.keys is my list. I want to insert a column in my data frame which will check if any keyword from the taglist is appeared in a specific column of my data frame then it will return name of that taglist in the new column.

Comment: if multiple keywords are there then there should be multiple tags in my new column separated by comma

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)
jobs.df %>% rowwise %>% mutate(
  cat = map(cat.keys, ~str_detect(Job.Title, fixed(.x)) %>% any) %>% 
    {names(.[.==TRUE])} %>% paste(collapse=" - ")
)
```

As you can see, "Director of IT - DeMolay International" also contains "Intern" and thus is considered in two classes.

You might want to reconsider your wording inside the list. For instance, using `Intern$` in the list and `regex(.x)` in the code yields different results which can also be interesting (better in some case, worst in another). This would need some regex work, though.

**EDIT:**
Using `rowwise` can indeed be pretty slow. You can use `apply`, which is much faster, on rows (`margin=1`) like this:

```
jobs.df$cat2=jobs.df %>% apply(1, function(x){
  map(cat.keys, ~str_detect(x["Job.Title"], fixed(.x)) %>% any) %>% 
    {names(.[.==TRUE])} %>% paste(collapse=" - ")
})
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem with this code is that it is time taking, so I am trying the same task with apply function. but not getting exactly how can I do this?

Comment: yes this is working fast but this is returning me a list and I want it as a new column in my data frame only

Comment: if this answer helped you, you may want to mark it as solved and/or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack` to convert named list to dataframe and then perform `merge` -

```
merge(jobs.df, stack(cat.keys), by.x = 'Job.Title', by.y = 'values')

#  Job.Title                  Company        ind
#1    Intern Big Brothers Big Sisters Internship
#2     Nurse       American Red Cross Healthcare
#3        RN       American Red Cross Healthcare
```